# How can I fix the on reload error on a React website hosted on Netlify without the TOML file?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

Without the [TOML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOML) file, the reload error occurs.

Comment: What are you talking about? Can you add some context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use _redirect file in your public directory. That worked for me.